# ASP.NET MVC 2 validation of Date using DataAnnotations not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, date, model

I am using the following in my model for a date control

```
   [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
   public DateTime txtDateAppCompletion { get; set; }
```

I also tried DataType.Date as I only want a date input.

```
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime txtDateAppCompletion { get; set; }
```

For some reason when I run the form and I type anything that is not a date it does not validate it, not on server or on client(client validation is enabled).

Any Idea why I am having this problems? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some research I found this in a Microsoft book.

> ■ Caution Even though [DataType] looks
>   like a validation attribute along with
>   the others in Data Annotations,
>   ASP.NET MVC does not treat it as one,
>   so don’t expect
>   [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] to
>   validate for legal e-mail addresses!
>   [DataType] is an anomaly; even though
>   it inherits from
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute,
>   its IsValid() method is hard-coded to
>   return true regardless of the
>   property’s value. Microsoft has
>   explained that [DataType] is only
>   meant to serve as a hint for
>   formatting data in a scaffolded UI...